# Regular Expression using C#

Tags: c#

This is my input:

> 27:15 And Rebekah took goodly raiment of her eldest son Esau, which^p
>   were with her in the house, and put them upon Jacob her younger son:^p
>   27:16 And she put the skins of the kids of the goats upon his hands,^p
>   and upon the smooth of his neck: 27:17 And she gave the meat^p and the
>   bread, which she had prepared, into the hand of her son Jacob.

Here ^p is the enter.

It should be add to database as `27:15 contents` in one line and `27:16 contents` in another...

Using regular expression I've tried :

```
var m = Regex.Match(line, @"\n\d+:");
if (m.Success)
 {
   html = html.Replace(m.Value, "</p>\n<p>" + m.Value);
 }
```

My Output is coming like this:

```
2
7:15 contents
```

i want to store `27:15 contents`.. I have tried and am not getting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var m = Regex.Match(line, @"(( )?\d+:\d+)")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your Regular Expression

```
var m = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+:\d+")
```

It will return you 27:15

Comment: Yes its coming But problem is when am storing to database in some sentense number will spilt like 2 in row and 2:15 in another row.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use following regex

```
(\d+:\d+)*
```

You can test the output on this site immidiately.

**[Regex Pal](http://regexpal.com/)**